# How to call an event handler on body tag only when all other event handlers fail?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a Jquery script where I have written few event handlers on some elements. If these two events are not called, I want an event to call. But somehow I'm not able to figure out a way. I used a boolean variable but doesn't seem to work. Here's my sample code:

```
    $(function(){
     var flag = false;
     $("input[type=text]").blur(function () {
            //some code
            flag = true;
        });
     $("input[type=password]").blur(function () {
           //some code
           flag = true;
        });

        if(flag!= true)
           $('body').click(function(event){
            alert(event.target.tagName);
           });
        }
      });
```

I want the click event on `body` tag to execute only when my first two event handlers are not executed. I know this is wrong. Please suggest a better way to check. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first handlers, accept the event argument and call [`event.stopPropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/Event.stopPropagation/) to prevent the event bubbling to the document. Something along these lines (you were mixing `click` and `blur`; I've used `click` consistently in the below):

```
$(function() {

    $("input[type=text]").click(function(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        //some code
    });
    $("input[type=password]").click(function(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        //some code
    });

    $('body').click(function(event) {
        alert(event.target.tagName);
    });
});
```

Your `flag` approach could work as well **provided** that nothing ever stops propagation (which is an assumption I wouldn't make), but you need to reset the flag, *and* your code at the end was putting the `if` *outside* the final event handler rather than *inside* it. Here's a fix (again with `click` consistently):

```
// ONLY WORKS IF NOTHING EVER STOPS PROPAGATION
$(function() {
    var flag = false;

    $("input[type=text]").click(function() {
        //some code
        flag = true;
    });
    $("input[type=password]").click(function() {
        //some code
        flag = true;
    });

    $('body').click(function(event) {
        if (flag) {                     // Check goes INSIDE the handler
            flag = false;               // Reset the flag, but otherwise don't do anything
        } else {
            alert(event.target.tagName);
        }
    });
});
```

I don't think I'd do it that way because it seems really fragile. Here's an example of it working, though:

```js
// ONLY WORKS IF NOTHING EVER STOPS PROPAGATION
$(function() {
    var flag = false;

    $("input[type=text]").click(function() {
        snippet.log("Click on field " + this.name);
        flag = true;
    });
    $("input[type=password]").click(function() {
        snippet.log("Click on field " + this.name);
        flag = true;
    });

    $('body').click(function(event) {
        if (flag) {                     // Check goes INSIDE the handler
            flag = false;               // Reset the flag, but otherwise don't do anything
        } else {
            snippet.log(
                "Click on body, target tagname: " +
                event.target.tagName
            );
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<div>
  <form>
    <input type="text" name="text1">
    <input type="text" name="text2">
    <input type="password" name="password1">
    <input type="password" name="password2">
  </form>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Actually, we can probably use a flag on the actual event, which would solve the problem of not having a means of resetting if something stops propagation:

```
$(function() {

    $("input[type=text]").click(function(event) {
        snippet.log("Click on field " + this.name);
        event.originalEvent.handled = true;
    });
    $("input[type=password]").click(function(event) {
        snippet.log("Click on field " + this.name);
        event.originalEvent.handled = true;
    });

    $('body').click(function(event) {
        if (!event.originalEvent.handled) {
            snippet.log(
                "Click on body, target tagname: " +
                event.target.tagName
            );
        }
    });
});
```

```js
$(function() {

    $("input[type=text]").click(function(event) {
        snippet.log("Click on field " + this.name);
        event.originalEvent.handled = true;
    });
    $("input[type=password]").click(function(event) {
        snippet.log("Click on field " + this.name);
        event.originalEvent.handled = true;
    });

    $('body').click(function(event) {
        if (!event.originalEvent.handled) {
            snippet.log(
                "Click on body, target tagname: " +
                event.target.tagName
            );
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<div>
  <form>
    <input type="text" name="text1">
    <input type="text" name="text2">
    <input type="password" name="password1">
    <input type="password" name="password2">
  </form>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Comment: I cannot stop propagation of events. The problem with the above usage of flag is that, body event handler is called during the document loading as well.

Comment: @NaveenBharadwaj: *"The problem with the above usage of flag is that, body event handler is called during the document loading as well. "* No it isn't. It's called when an event occurs.

Comment: oh yeah correct..but I dont need to call body event handler when other event is registered. only when none of my other events are registered, body event handler should trigger

Comment: @NaveenBharadwaj: What do you mean "registered"? The usual meaning of that word doesn't seem to fit with what you're saying: When you *register* for an event, you're hooking up a handler. But your question seems to be asking about when the event *occurs*. BTW, I added a third option which lets us use a flag but without worrying about something stopping propagation.

Comment: I used "registered" in the context of the variable name you used. I think your third option should work. I'm checking. Thank you.

Comment: @NaveenBharadwaj: I'm still not following, but it's not important. :-) Hopefully that sorts things out for you.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work like that, if you still wanna do it then move the body event in a function and call it in your blur event.So it will attach a click event on a body when ever the blur event gets triggered.

But i would suggest you to move the flag variable inside the body click event. There is no harm on attaching a click event(wont take much memory).

```
 $(function(){
 var flag = false;
 $("input[type=text]").blur(function () {
        //some code
        flag = true;
    });
 $("input[type=password]").blur(function () {
       //some code
       flag = true;
    });

    $('body').click(function(event){
          if(flag!= true){   
             alert(event.target.tagName);
          }
    });

  });
```

Comment: I tried that as well. I want that function only when none of my event handlers are executed. I'm not able to achieve that

Comment: I want your attachEvent() method to execute when none of the other events get executed. Where and when can I call that?

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
   $(function(){
      var flag = false;
      $('#test').on("blur keydown change",function(e){
         flag=true;
      });
      $('#body').click(function(event){
       if(flag) {
         alert(event.target.tagName);
       } else {
         alert('flag is false');
       } 
     });
   });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/y7q5vbz8/1/